# How i can put in the middle of a navbar for exemple the ActionLink "Add Pictures"?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to put in the middle of the NavBar theActionLink "Add Pictures"

```
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

           </button>
           @Html.ActionLink("PicWorld", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new
           {
               @class = "navbar-brand",
               style = "color: Red"
           })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                </ul>
                <ul   class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "AddPictures", "Pictures")</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

i want to make that line `"<li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "AddPictures", "Pictures")</li>` to be in the middle of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand, but why don't you just put it between your 'About' and 'Contact' navbar items?

Eg:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Pictures", "AddPictures", "Pictures")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because i want to put the Add Pictures on the middle of the Navigation Bar not in the same corner with the rest.